# Can python webbrowser module work with cgi?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, cgi, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a url from an html form submit action using the python cgi and webbrowser modules. I am able to launch the url on localhost with 
`python -m webbrowser -t "http://myhost.com/path/to/some/file.html"` however with 
`webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)` in my cgi script, apache serves a blank page and no errors are printed to the page. The location box of my firefox browser shows 'http://myhost.com/my_script.cgi?Submit=Submit' instead of the destination url.

If the webbrowser module cannot be used in this context, I'm confused about what purpose it  actually serves. If I use a url as the form action, the page would be served to the client, but my script needs to process variables passed by a previous html form in order to determine the url and then serve that url to the client. Let me know what I'm missing, thanks.

Comment: are you trying to run the webbrowser command inside your CGI script to proxy data to pass back to the user?

Comment: yes, but I'm starting with a static url to figure out how to proceed:

`if 'Submit' in form:
        url = "http://www.python.org"  
        try: 
            webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, yes, you are confusing what the webbrowser library is supposed to do.
If you run the webbrowser command inside the cgi, it will attempt to open a webbrowser on the server running your cgi script (as whatever user is running the cgi).  This will probably not work.  what I think you want to have happen is your cgi script should return the appropriate HTTP "commands" to the browser to cause it to redirect.  As an example:

```
if "Submit" in form:
   url = "http://www.python.org #or do whatever processing is needed to calculate the new URL
   print "Status: 302" #this tells the browser the result is a redirect
   print "Location: " + url #this tells the browser where to redirect
   print "" #send two new lines to end the HTTP header
```

Note that if you were using django or another library (and I expect even just the cgi library counts), there's probably a higher level way to do this, but this should work just about anywhere.  You could also do things with META-refresh inside HTML etc.

Comment: I think that the default python cgi behavior is to load the path to the script with the argument passed by the submit button, so I'm seeing `http://path/to/my_script.cgi?URL=Python`, in the Location bar of my browser, with `Status: 302 Location: http://www.python.org` in a blank page. I don't know enough about apache config on localhost to fix that but did this: `<form action="${path_to_file}"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go to ${place_name}">` Also, a styled href works: `<a class="button" href="${path_to_file}">Go to ${place_name}</a>` So I'll use the href for now. Thanks!